# Troubleshooting HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure, AppPool is invalid

Tags: asp.net-core

I cloned a c# api.net core 2.1 solution from a Git repository in BitBucket.
The solution project works fine on the machine that pushed to the repository.

I created the wwwroot folder and the logs folder as they were missing.

When I run the solulution I get

```
HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

Common causes of this issue:
The application process failed to start
The application process started but then stopped
The application process started but failed to listen on the configured port

Troubleshooting steps:
Check the system event log for error messages
Enable logging the application process’ stdout messages
Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect

For more information visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=808681
```

I checked the event log and I see

```
The directory specified for caching compressed content
C:\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files\MySolution AppPool is invalid.
Static compression is being disabled.
```

Searching for instructions on how to "    Enable logging the application process’ stdout messages"

I see [this advice on editing web.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

However there is no web.config in my solution, only appsettings.json

I had a look at [this link on the Static Compression](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mayurpatankar/2018/02/16/iis-static-compression-the-directory-specified-for-caching-compressed-content-is-invalid-static-compression-is-disabled-warnings-in-event-viewer2264/)  however I am just pressing F5 to run so why would I be investigating IIS?

Comment: reading https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mayurpatankar/2018/02/16/iis-static-compression-the-directory-specified-for-caching-compressed-content-is-invalid-static-compression-is-disabled-warnings-in-event-viewer2264/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had  dot net core 2.1 sdk installed on my machine where as the machine that pushed had 2.1.2